# Should [queryover] and [nhibernate-queryover] be aliased together?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I think that [queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover) and [nhibernate-queryover](/questions/tagged/nhibernate-queryover) should be synonyms.

The wiki of [queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover):

> QueryOver is a strongly-typed fluent-like wrapper on top of NHibernate ICritieria, a database-agnostic query API that supports query composition.

and the wiki of [nhibernate-queryover](/questions/tagged/nhibernate-queryover):

> NHibernate QueryOver is a strongly-typed fluent-like wrapper on top of NHibernate ICritieria, a database-agnostic query API that supports query composition.

[queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover) has 354 questions, while [nhibernate-queryover](/questions/tagged/nhibernate-queryover) has 191 questions.

Comment: I guess nhibernate-queryover should remain, because its name is more specific.